# 4k external monitor shows 3840x2160 and 1920x1080 but not 2560x1440

Tags: macos, display, screen

I'm using a external monitor with 3840x2160 resolution but it's completely unusable at that resolution (27", too tiny).

I want to try it at 2560x1440 but MacOS doesn't even show that option.

Is there a solution to show icons larger on screen?

Comment: Are you connecting via an HDMI port? That might be limiting your resolution options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimum scaling for that size display on MacOS is **1920 x 1080 (HiDPI)**, which will give the "Retina display" HiDPI effect, making the display objects appear at 'normal' size, but using the doubled pixel density to create a higher-resolution image.

(Another way to look at it is that the display is actually at 3840 x 2160, but the OS magnifies everything x2, to avoid the tiny sizes that you have seen.)

Any scaling size with **(HiDPI)** after it will use Retina scaling to some degree.

MacOS will display a larger range of Scaling options if you hold down Alt and click on the "Scaled" button in System Preferences > Displays.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that was an issue of the previous versions of MacOS, because MacOS Catalina allows 1920x1080, 2304x1296, 2560x1440, 3008x1692, 3200x1800, 3360x1890 scaled modes on 27" 4K external monitor.